# CentOS yum install gcc error: glibc-common conflicts with glibc

Tags: linux, gcc, centos, glibc

I met a problem with installing gcc on my CentOS.

Outputs of my command `sudo yum install gcc`:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * addons: centos.ustc.edu.cn
 * base: centos.ustc.edu.cn
 * extras: mirror.bit.edu.cn
 * updates: centos.ustc.edu.cn
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package gcc.x86_64 0:4.1.2-54.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: cpp = 4.1.2-54.el5 for package: gcc
--> Processing Dependency: libgomp >= 4.1.2-54.el5 for package: gcc
--> Processing Dependency: libgcc >= 4.1.2-54.el5 for package: gcc
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-devel >= 2.2.90-12 for package: gcc
--> Running transaction check
---> Package cpp.x86_64 0:4.1.2-54.el5 set to be updated
---> Package glibc-devel.x86_64 0:2.5-118.el5_10.2 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-headers = 2.5-118.el5_10.2 for package: glibc-devel
--> Processing Dependency: glibc = 2.5-118.el5_10.2 for package: glibc-devel
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-headers for package: glibc-devel
---> Package libgcc.i386 0:4.1.2-54.el5 set to be updated
---> Package libgcc.x86_64 0:4.1.2-54.el5 set to be updated
---> Package libgomp.x86_64 0:4.4.7-1.el5 set to be updated
--> Running transaction check
--> Processing Dependency: glibc = 2.5-49 for package: nscd
---> Package glibc.x86_64 0:2.5-118.el5_10.2 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-common = 2.5-118.el5_10.2 for package: glibc
---> Package glibc-headers.x86_64 0:2.5-118.el5_10.2 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: kernel-headers >= 2.2.1 for package: glibc-headers
--> Processing Dependency: kernel-headers for package: glibc-headers
--> Running transaction check
---> Package glibc-common.x86_64 0:2.5-118.el5_10.2 set to be updated
---> Package kernel-headers.x86_64 0:2.6.18-371.4.1.el5 set to be updated
---> Package nscd.x86_64 0:2.5-118.el5_10.2 set to be updated
--> Processing Conflict: glibc-common conflicts glibc > 2.5
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
glibc-common-2.5-118.el5_10.2.x86_64 from updates has depsolving problems
  --> glibc-common conflicts with glibc
Error: glibc-common conflicts with glibc
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I can not figure out what the `conflict` means, and I found nothing after a google.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Off-topic for SO; belongs on [su] or [unix.se]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
rpm -e glibc-2.5-118.el5_10.2.x86_64 glibc-common-2.5-118.el5_10.2.x86_64
```

then...

```
yum -y upgrade glibc glibc-*
```

It should fix you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Run your command and I got these output.
 glibc-2.5-49.x86_64
 glibc-2.9-2.i686
 glibc-common-2.5-49.x86_64
 glibc-common-2.9-2.i386
Then I should run command like this?
  sudo rpm -e glibc-2.9-2.i686 glibc-common-2.9-2.i386 glibc-2.9-2.i686 glibc-common-2.5-49.x86_64

Comment: which output you get? please place your output in question window

Comment: glibc-2.5-49.x86_64
 glibc-2.9-2.i686
 glibc-common-2.5-49.x86_64
 glibc-common-2.9-2.i386

Comment: I got something like this.        "libpthread.so.0()(64bit) is needed by (installed) nscd-2.5-49.x86_64
        libpthread.so.0()(64bit) is needed by (installed) m2crypto-0.16-6.el5.6.x86_64
        libpthread.so.0()(64bit) is needed by (installed) python-elementtree-1.2.6-5.x86_64
        libpthread.so.0()(64bit) is needed by (installed) python-sqlite-1.1.7-1.2.1.x86_64"

Comment: hello hello. It seems that I can not erase glibc packages.

Comment: It seems,You are trying install 32-bit package (i386) on 64-bit system (x86_64).